# adding multiple inherited objects to a container class

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, containers, implementation

I have a program that is well under way, but I can't seem to wrap my ahead around how to add certain classes to a container.

I'm creating a java program for just a 2D person. I have an abstract class, BodyPart (which all body parts share in common), DrawablePart and ContainerPart class implements the abstract class, where Drawable parts include implemented classes such as head, legs, feet, etc; And ContainerParts include implemented classes such as person > upperbody & lowerbody.

The only part I have left to do is create the upperbody and lowerbody classes derived from the container class, which has an array of BodyParts.

Let's say I'm working on LowerBody container, derived from ContainerPart. How is it possible to have a LowerBody constructor that can contain arrays of Legs and Feet (which are derived from DrawablePart)? I would like to have LowerBody and UpperBody derive from Avatar container, which derives from ContainerPart.

I know it's hard getting an answer without showing my code, but I think someone can explain it to me with this UML diagram I created below from my classes.

**Here is the UML diagram**:

[image]

Here is a ContainerPart constructor with an array of BodyParts (super is from BodyPart), which is what I want, but I need certain parts like Leg and Feet in the constructor of LowerBody:

```
    public ContainerPart(String name, String color, int xCoord, int yCoord, BodyPart[] yourParts) {
        super(name, color, xCoord, yCoord);
        parts = yourParts;
}
```

In my container class I have an instance field for an array of BodyParts, as seen in the constructor above. But when I try to use more than one derived BodyPart, I get this:

[image]

But, if I just have one, say "yourFoot" in super(), it'll work.

Comment: I'm thinking that Drawable part should be an interface, not a class.

Comment: that would make more sense, but I need to focus on the container part for now.

Comment: It would still help out. Everything should be a Container when you think of it, and most all should be Drawable as well.

Comment: I'd be tempted to separate the 2 problems. That is, model the person and the representation separately. You may also wish to consider the rule "favour composition over inheritance". For example, you could have a renderer that knows how to draw a person, rather than force a person to be Drawable

Comment: containers aren't Drawable, and I'm not inclined to working on the drawing section until I know how to add certain body part objects to LowerBody and UpperBody.

Comment: i love how I get upvoted and once I don't accept someone's answer, they remove it. I'm sorry you didn't answer my question correctly? people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't add this as a comment hence putting here.

If I understand correctly, you have something like below (`your real constructor has more arguments`):

```
public abstract class BodyPart {
  private String name;
  private String color;
      ......
      ......
}


public class DrawablePart extends BodyPart {

    public DrawablePart(){
        super();
    }
}

public class ContainerPart extends BodyPart {

    public ContainerPart(String name, String color, int xCoord, int yCoord, BodyPart[] yourParts){
        super(......);
        ...........
     }
}

public class Legs extends DrawablePart {

    public Legs(){
        super();
    }
}
```

Now you want to create `LowerBody` as:

```
public class LowerBody extends ContainerPart {

    public LowerBody(Legs[] legs, Feet[] feet, String name, String color, int xCoord, int yCoord){
         super(name, color,xCoord, yCoord, legs);
         ........
         .......
    }

    public LowerBody(Legs leg, Feet feet, String name, String color, int xCoord, int yCoord){
        super(name, color,xCoord, yCoord, new BodyPart[]{leg, feet});
    }
}
```

If yes, what is the problem? It should work fine. If I am missing anything, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a silly question. Why not just have LowerBody extend Avatar? You'd still get the benefits of ContainerPart.

Or you can add a new constructor:

```
public LowerBody(List<DrawableParts> parts) {

}
```